# Link to anchor inside tabbed content from an external link

Tags: jquery

Link to an anchor within tabbed  content from an **external link**  [Go to anchor](http://www.canberra.edu.au/media/test/bookmark.html/#test). Script needs to be added as a global file across all pages/template. Example of what I have so [I have so far](http://www.canberra.edu.au/media/test/bookmark.html).

click on the `<a goto="stuff" href="#test">Go to stuff</a>` /which goes to the ***third tab***.

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/TGMDd/2/)**

Comment: Looks like a job description.

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: thanks for instructions.

Comment: No, not a job description and I thought I was clear bart s. I'm trying to get a link from another page to go to an anchor within a tabbed section where the anchor is. At the moment the link only works on on the **same page** where the anchor is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that $(window.location.hash) evaluates to $('#test') so it looks for an element with an ID="test". Such element does not exist on your page.

Using a link like this:

http://www.canberra.edu.au/media/test/bookmark.html/#test

would usually indicate that you want to go to content marked with anchor name="test".

In your example I can see at least two anchors with the same name attribute:

```
<a name="test"></a>
```

This is wrong - anchor names must be unique:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#idx-anchor-4

So once you fix this and have a unique anchor name, you can then use href instead of your goto attribute.
It's also a good idea to use both **name** and **id**:

```
<a id="test" name="test"></a>
```

which will make $(window.location.hash) work as expected.

So now this should activate the correct tab:

```
var $targetAnchor = $(window.location.hash);
tabId = $targetAnchor.closest('.tab-content').attr('id');
$tabs.find('a[href=#' + tabId + ']').click();
```

And this should work for scrolling:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $targetAnchor.offset().top
});
```

Comment: Thanks Kfej - I have been looking at this for too long and missed that second anchor. Ok so far so good, how can I carry over scrollTo the anchor as well?

Comment: not sure how to put that all together - could you add it here Please! I'd be really grateful :-) http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/TGMDd/2/

Comment: No, for now leave your anchor click handler as it was - it worked just fine, right? Add my code to the end of $(document).ready for handling incoming external requests. I can edit your jsfiddle when I have a minute.

Comment: Kfrej You absolutely **ROCK!** Perfecto. can this go into a global script file? i.e will it affect any links I'm trying to link to and from?

Comment: Nope, tried it locally and not a problem. What I had before somehow interfered with the link. Thank you so much again, would you be ok if I used it?

Comment: Sure I would be ok. That's what stackoverflow is for. I wrote the answer so you could use it. You should perhpas spend some time and improve the javascript a bit - e.g. if you change the click handler you won't need that _goto_ attribute.

Comment: I'm still learning - I'm more of a web designer than a developer, that said I love jQuery and what it has to offer. In jobs I have always landed the designer roles but I try and keep up-to-date with as much javascript as I can.