# Anchor Links to Content Inside Bootstrap Tabs

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my first time asking here, and I'm honestly just desperate to know if this is doable.
I have very little knowledge when it comes to JavaScript, so I apologize if I am unable to properly explain some parts.

So I have tabbed content created using bootstrap tabs.
Everything is on the same page.
I'd like to be able to jump from anchor links outside the tabbed content to the content inside tabs. The first one works just fine, because it links to an active tab. But how can I jump to content inside inactive tabs?

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>Anchor Link</th>
  <td>
   <a class="tab-anchor" data-day="one" href="#act01">Link to Content Inside Tab 1</a>
  </td>
  <td>
   <a class="tab-anchor" data-day="two" href="act02">Link to Content Inside Tab 2</a>
  </td>
  <td>
   <a class="tab-anchor" data-day="three" href="act03">Link to Content Inside Tab 3</a>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>



<div class="c_tab_body">
 <div class="c_btn_tab nav nav-tabs">
  <a id="day-one" class="nav-link col-4 active" href="#day01" data-toggle="tab">Day 1</a>
  <a id="day-two" class="nav-link col-4" href="#day02" data-toggle="tab">Day 2</a>
  <a id="day-three" class="nav-link col-4" href="#day03" data-toggle="tab">Day 3</a>
 </div>
 
 <div class="c_tab_inner tab-content">
  <div id="day01" class="tab-pane fade show active">
   <table class="c_table_type01 table table-bordered">
    <tr id="act01">
     <th>Anchor Content</th>
     <td>Content I need to jump to upon clicking anchor link</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </div>

  <div id="day02" class="tab-pane fade">
   <table class="c_table_type01 table table-bordered">
    <tr id="act02">
     <th>Anchor Content</th>
     <td>Content I need to jump to upon clicking anchor link</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </div>

  <div id="day03" class="tab-pane fade">
   <table class="c_table_type01 table table-bordered">
    <tr id="act03">
     <th>Anchor Content</th>
     <td>Content I need to jump to upon clicking anchor link</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

For now my javascript looks like this

```
   // Link to Tabbed Content
   $('.tab-anchor').on('click', function(e){
      let day = $(this).data('day');
      $tab = $('#' + day);
      if ($tab.hasClass('active')) {
          return;
      }
      switch (day) {
          case 'day-one':       
              break;
          case 'day-two':
              $('#day-one').removeClass('active');
              $('#day-two').addClass('active');
              $('#day-three').removeClass('active');
              $('#day01').removeClass('active show');
              $('#day02').addClass('active show');
              $('#day03').removeClass('active show');
              break;
          case 'day-three':                
              break;
          default:
              break;
      }
   });
```

I'm so sorry if this looks so confusing!
I'd be very grateful for any suggestions or advice to point me to the right direction,
as I am honestly very lost right now....

Answer (score 0):

I might be a bit late, since it's been three months, but I've been searching for similar solution, yet linking to tab itself, not within. I'm not any good with JS either, but recent intense googling and copy-pasting have given me some basic knowledge on it.

I tried finding a solution for your question, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616833/link-to-anchor-inside-tabbed-content-from-an-external-link) looks close enough to what you needed, especially this piece of code:

```
var $targetAnchor = $(window.location.hash);
tabId = $targetAnchor.closest('.tab-pane').attr('id');
$tabs.find('a[href=#' + tabId + ']').click();
```

It finds the closest tab-pane class, gets its id and imitates click on a tab with same `href`; Though you might need to reorganize your tabs or maybe simply add "tabs" class to your tr. I'm not sure how to properly test it and whether you still need it at all, but I hope I was of any help.